# Prevent initializing classes that extend a singleton class

Tags: python, inheritance, singleton

I would like to prevent multiple instantiation of inherited classes. The singleton pattern seemed appropriate for this task, but I don't quite get the result that I expected.

This is my code example:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class Config(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print('initialized')


class DevelopConfig(Config):
    pass


class TestingConfig(Config):
    pass


foo = DevelopConfig()
bar = TestingConfig()
```

Executing this, I would expect to see a single "initialized" as output, but it appears twice. Any ideas on how to prevent multiple instances of these classes? What did I miss?

EDIT: The ultimate goal is preventing multiple concurring configurations. If there is a smarter way, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem behind what you are experiencing is `cls` is not actually what you think. Just because the variable is called `cls` doesn't mean it's the class object, and in this case it is actually `self`, the created object.

This can be seen if you add a `print` statement to your Singleton class:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(cls)
        #etc...


>>> foo = DevelopConfig()
<class '__main__.DevelopConfig'>
initialized
>>> bar = TestingConfig()
<class '__main__.TestingConfig'>
initialized
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-callable-objects)

> `object.__call__(self[, args...])`
>
> Called when the instance is “called”
>   as a function; if this method is defined, `x(arg1, arg2, ...)` is a
>   shorthand for `x.__call__(arg1, arg2, ...)`.

---

I would suggest dropping the dictionary, you shouldn't need it if you only want one instance to exist. This simplifies the problem.

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instance = None
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not Singleton._instance:
            Singleton._instance = super(Singleton, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return Singleton._instance

class Config(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        print('initialized')


class DevelopConfig(Config):
    pass


class TestingConfig(Config):
    pass
```

This produces:

```
>>> foo = DevelopConfig()
initialized
>>> bar = TestingConfig()

>>> foo
<__main__.DevelopConfig object at 0x00000259CE2FD080>
>>> bar
<__main__.DevelopConfig object at 0x00000259CE2FD080>
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. Perfect answer. :)